# How to access 2D Array without specifing the size

Tags: java, arrays

```
int a[][]=new int[3][];
```

I am not specifying size of columns here, so if I want to provide column values dynamically, how can I do it without getting `NullPointerException` esp using for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign to each row an array of different length :

```
int[][] a =new int[3][];
a[0] = new int[5];
a[1] = new int[3];
a[2] = new int[10];
```

Then you can assign values in a loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = ........
    }
}
```